# How do I delete a member of $_REQUEST?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$_REQUEST['delete_me'];

Array ( 
 [action] => test
 [city_name] => Orlando 
 [delete_me] => - 
);
```

Can I just delete it or will setting it to `$_REQUEST['delete_me'] = "";` do the trick?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what [halfdan said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727574/how-do-i-delete-an-element-in-request/3727606#3727606), you should probably be using `$_GET` or `$_POST` or equivalent, unless you really do require it to be that ambiguous.

Taking values from `$_REQUEST` can make XSS that much easier... when you want POST values and a malicious user just appends them to a query string.

Answer (score 12):

```
unset($_REQUEST['delete_me']);
```

See the PHP manual for more information about [unset](http://php.net/unset).